# Me gustaría hacer algo en C++ como el get y el set de C# por ejemplo

Tags: c++

```
class my_class{


int arr[5];

};

int main(){
  my_class example = new my_class();
  example.x = 5 //sea equivalente a arr[0] = 5
}
```

O sea, quiero poder acceder y/o modificar arr[0] de my_class a partir de instancia.x
Sé que puedo hacerlo con un método, pero me gustaría hacerlo con una palabra

Comment: Español amigo, y un poco mas de detalle de tu pregunta se agradece mucho

Comment: Perdona, es mi primera pregunta y no tenía muy claro cómo funcionaba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa referencias:

```
struct my_class{
    int arr[5]{};
    int &x;
    int &y;
    int &z;
    int &v;
    int &w;

    my_class() :
        x{arr[0]},
        y{arr[1]},
        z{arr[2]},
        v{arr[3]},
        w{arr[4]}
    {}
};
```

El siguiente código:

```
int main()
{
    my_class c;
    c.x = 5;
    c.z = 2;
    c.w = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
        std::cout << '[' << i << "] = " << c.arr[i] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Produce la [siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##RY7dasMwDEavrafQOlgSupW2W2@SbC/SmRHcdBgapzhO82P87JnsYHZjnSPkTxL3@9uvEMvyLJW49ZcaS9l2RtdV8wVA0AuDzfQjblXXWWBSGay0Pp@4dcWqL2OEKcIc4RFhKABYzEkzzIGx0fqkPXevJFOQwypzkOMqjyDvqwxBPrgDZh3QCeDjm0qqNAP7vwIFbRa7ET/xFGgmOgYaiA7@nGurMfXfJXX2BZUnP43brcxoVWcueS7a3mBZYnJOfJH@2XCa33gSO3@N5GHiWyU@Vdem14rywC3LHw):

> ```
> [0] = 5
> [1] = 0
> [2] = 2
> [3] = 0
> [4] = 1
> ```