# Me gustaría hacer una distinción de casos dentro de una clase que usa templates en C++:

Tags: c++, diseño-de-clases

Tengo la siguiente clase:

```
template <typename T, int cant>
class myVector{
T *vector = new T[cant];
}
```

Quiero acceder a acceder a una instancia de la clase para el caso específico:

```
myVector<T,2> vec2.x;
vec2.y;
```

De forma que sea equivalente a acceder y modificar vector[0], vector[1] y para el caso:

```
 myVector<T,3> vec3.x;
vec3.y;
vec3.z;
```

vector[0], vector[1] y vector[2]

Pero no quisiera que esto fuera posible fuera de estos casos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa herencia, especialización de plantillas, y [referencias](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/488555/me-gustar%c3%ada-hacer-algo-en-c-como-el-get-y-el-set-de-c-por-ejemplo/488579#488579):

Empieza con una clase base con toda la funcionalidad general:

```
// Clase base, con todos los metodos.
template <typename T, int cant>
struct vector_base
{
    // Constructor por defecto, pone todos los datos a 0
    vector_base() = default;
    // Copia otro vector del mismo tamaño
    vector_base(const vector_base &v) { std::copy(v.vector, v.vector + cant, vector); }
    // Copia una formación del mismo tamaño
    vector_base(const T (&v)[cant]) { std::copy(v, v + cant, vector); }

    // Concatena con otro vector
    template <int sz>
    auto operator+(const vector_base<T, sz> &mv)
    {
        vector_base<T, cant + sz> result;
        std::copy(vector, vector + cant, result.vector);
        std::copy(mv.vector, mv.vector + sz, result.vector + cant);
        return result;
    }

    T vector[cant] {};
};

// Operador de escritura en flujo de salida
template <typename T, int cant>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const vector_base<T, cant> &v)
{
    for (const auto &valor : v.vector)
        o << valor << ' ';
    return o;
}
```

Y luego, haz las especializaciones

```
// Clase derivada, caso general
template <typename T, int cant>
struct myVector : public vector_base<T, cant>
{
    // Traemos a este ámbito los constructores de la clase base
    using vector_base<T, cant>::vector_base;
};

template <typename T>
struct myVector<T, 3> : public vector_base<T, 3>
{
    // Traemos a este ámbito los constructores de la clase base
    using vector_base<T, 3>::vector_base;
    // Traemos a este ámbito la formación de la clase base
    using vector_base<T, 3>::vector;
    T &x;
    T &y;
    T &z;

    myVector() :
        x{vector[0]},
        y{vector[1]},
        z{vector[2]}
    {}
};
```

Puedes usarlo así:

```
int main()
{
    int valores[] {10, 20, 30, 40};

    myVector<int, 2> v2;            // por defecto
    myVector<int, 3> v3;            // por defecto
    myVector<int, 4> v4(valores);   // mediante formación
    myVector<int, 5> v5;            // por defecto
    auto v6 = v2 + v4;              // copia y operador +

    std::cout
        << "v2 = " << v2 << '\n'
        << "v3 = " << v3 << '\n'
        << "v4 = " << v4 << '\n'
        << "v5 = " << v5 << '\n'
        << "v6 = " << v6;

    v2.x = 20; // Error, no tiene miembro 'x'
    v3.x = 30; // Correcto.
    v4.x = 40; // Error, no tiene miembro 'x'
    v5.x = 50; // Error, no tiene miembro 'x'

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código "funcionando" en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVTLbuIwFF0nX3HVkSgIBmgSWATKZj5gNtVsOtXITQyTUWJHsRMVEN/OHDsJj5SqlQjx9bnP4@NEef49SpnYHI/fEhGlZcxpmUilC86ylXveY@lGFon@i013MqEfKVOcXvE3okgK0jKWilI8Gbfrsat5lqdMI1Zvcy5YxulpRInQFDGhVy5qlJGmikdaFn9MKnfvOhdmf0CPFPM1K1O9uEZQUl2FUq8a0J6UjsMwkvm2X41rdETtioa28KgJGyzocCvpE/WR69m4vnRSIvRWEtc5j2rGU7uV67BSS5I5Lxjchu8bXoILOFIvqwaug8GdDmjKoJrxKbiqKXAummmnu56tdh233V2FZGdOsgtS1K4T1iSz0QXXZSHOHZhpn5qiNUe0Pyxc/Iwqfpp5Y2SAYriKoJeyYMQFrdPynzS7iqVJzL6gDTTdqJB6LY3LZb8DWPG9J9YmMZIwilqjn4Z/eyi9iqXYCk/CAP@OpOWSagCLe7rHrM3sEuNdaD7mRVKxmJkqStKGCzSXflXt2fZXzXFIefmaJtHN1k3bpUrE5iYahhe7Nfe3qr@raRL4qw8r@x@X9bs1P3NbGJX03urXtn7t0KfT9oK7HYL2t30jpenLYQR729oPtb1rbe8Fl3V/sMMaUjOWiL49XmPZg@PqGWJ8mI7Iw@PjCaaHy5rmcgJcUeUtHAcHmlulrg3Y9QJPlf@pVwCvoN9UHyyMd8bjBIfECbLLWJRI0Q2aIWh2I7UVZzXHN6/ycAWroPbB1U0YbetviblbQ4zUXOpSgyPo9Q4Rj3RnNexZAf8W9y3knyC/CwUnKOhCsxM060LzEzQ39E4mlTd@w543NV9p3659swYSWCtorJm1ZlMT1twurA/H438)</kbd>.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudó mucho, pero hay alguna forma de usar herencia en ese caso, para no tener que reescribir todos los métodos de la primera clase en cada caso especial?

Comment: Claro, por favor incluye lo que necesitas para que pueda editar la pregunta de manera acorde.

Comment: Necesito 3 constructores (por defecto, de copia y a partir de un array), además necesito realizar operaciones simples como suma de vectores. Ya los tengo hechos para la clase principal, me gustaría reutilizarlos en los casos especiales

Comment: @rocioog00 no es exactamente lo que he pedido, así que no se si seré capaz de responder a lo que necesitas ó_ò

Comment: `vec<T, cant> operator+ (vec<T, cant> a){`
        `T sum[cant];`
        `T *vec_a = a.get_vector();`

        `for(int i = 0; i < cant; i++){`
            `sum[i] = vec_a[i]+vector[i];`
        `}`

        `return vec<T, cant>(sum)`;
   ` }`  Tengo este método que es un método y me gustaría poder usarlo en el caso vec<T,2>, vec<T,3> sin tener que reescribir todo el método para esos casos.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta, en los comentarios no se ve bien.